# MySQL Multiple Joins in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
  dashboard_data.headline,
  dashboard_data.message,
  dashboard_messages.image_id 
FROM dashboard_data
INNER JOIN dashboard_messages
  ON dashboard_message_id = dashboard_messages.id
```

So I am using an `INNER JOIN` and grabbing the `image_id`.  So now, I want to take that image_id and turn it into `images.filename` from the images table.

How can I add that in to my query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+multiple+joins

Answer (score 258, accepted):

You can simply add another join like this:

```
SELECT dashboard_data.headline, dashboard_data.message, dashboard_messages.image_id, images.filename
FROM dashboard_data 
    INNER JOIN dashboard_messages 
        ON dashboard_message_id = dashboard_messages.id
    INNER JOIN images
        ON dashboard_messages.image_id = images.image_id
```

However be aware that, because it is an `INNER JOIN`, if you have a message without an image, the entire row will be skipped. If this is a possibility, you may want to do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` which will return all your dashboard messages and an image_filename only if one exists (otherwise you'll get a null)

```
SELECT dashboard_data.headline, dashboard_data.message, dashboard_messages.image_id, images.filename
FROM dashboard_data 
    INNER JOIN dashboard_messages 
        ON dashboard_message_id = dashboard_messages.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN images
        ON dashboard_messages.image_id = images.image_id
```

Comment: anybody know how this actually works?  Is the second join joining the results of the first join with table 3, or is it joining table 1 with table 3 separately? (i.e., joining table 1 with table 2, and then joining table 1 separately with table 3, then returning it all back?)  Does that make sense?

I ask because I've been doing multi-table joins like this, and sometimes get unexpected results.

Comment: That's what the ON clause will tell you. The ON clause for the 2nd join (joining the third table) is joining dashboard_messages to images on the image_id field in each table. So, in this case it's A to B then B to C. It's under your control. You could make it A to B and A to C if you need

Comment: This query works all the time! For me, 2 yrs ago it worked on another MySQL Database, this time it worked on another Database. Thanks.

Comment: @AaronWallentine Can you give an example of unexpected results? Or any example when the order matters? Your question makes sense, but I think `join` operations always commute: `A~B~C` is the same as `(A~B)~C`, which is the same as `A~(B~C)`. This is because any join `A~B` is a Cartesian product of rows filtered by an appropriate condition. `A~B~C` is a Cartesian product of three relations, filtered by the conjunction of the two condition. The last statement is intuitively clear, but must be proved by showing that filtering for `A~B` can be postponed until after the second Cartesian product.

Answer (score 17):

Just add another join:

```
SELECT dashboard_data.headline,
       dashboard_data.message,
       dashboard_messages.image_id,
       images.filename 
FROM dashboard_data 
    INNER JOIN dashboard_messages
            ON dashboard_message_id = dashboard_messages.id 
    INNER JOIN images
            ON dashboard_messages.image_id = images.image_id
```

Answer (score 9):

I shared my experience of using two LEFT JOINS in a single SQL query.

I have 3 tables:

Table 1) Patient consists columns PatientID, PatientName

Table 2) Appointment consists columns AppointmentID, AppointmentDateTime, PatientID, DoctorID

Table 3) Doctor consists columns DoctorID, DoctorName

---

Query:

```
SELECT Patient.patientname, AppointmentDateTime, Doctor.doctorname

FROM Appointment 

LEFT JOIN Doctor ON Appointment.doctorid = Doctor.doctorId  //have doctorId column common

LEFT JOIN Patient ON Appointment.PatientId = Patient.PatientId      //have patientid column common

WHERE Doctor.Doctorname LIKE 'varun%' // setting doctor name by using LIKE

AND Appointment.AppointmentDateTime BETWEEN '1/16/2001' AND '9/9/2014' //comparison b/w dates 

ORDER BY AppointmentDateTime ASC;  // getting data as ascending order
```

---

I wrote the solution to get [date format like "mm/dd/yy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326709/removing-time-from-datetime-in-c-sharp-and-retaining-datetime-format) (under my name "VARUN TEJ REDDY")

Answer (score 6):

Multi joins in SQL work by progressively creating derived tables one after the other.
See this link explaining the process:

https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/multiple-joins-work-just-like-single-joins/

Comment: Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.