# Left outer join and sum issue

Tags: mysql, sum, left-join

I need a query. I'm trying to sum of one field with joined tables. Some records not in second table. So this records sum should be zero. But the query only sum the records which are in the second table.

```
select s.*,sum(sd.fiyat) as konak from fuar_sozlesme1 s 
left outer join fuar_sozlesme1_detay sd on (sd.sozlesme_id = s.id)
```

------EDIT-------

I added `group by` into the query and solved my problem. Here is the new ;

```
select s.*,sum(sd.fiyat) as konak from fuar_sozlesme1 s 
left outer join fuar_sozlesme1_detay sd on (sd.sozlesme_id = s.id)
group by sd.sozlesme_id
```

Comment: If your question was understandable, you'd have many answers within minutes. Explain better, please.

Comment: @tombom        I'm sorry, but I don't how I explain better. I just want to a query that is sum a field with left join.But some records are not in the second table with same id.So, that is not completely union query. I solved my problem with group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinik you need to use [`IFNULL(sd.fiyat,0)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) instead of `sd.fiyat` to get zeros for the `NULL` values coming from the second table because of  the `LEFT JOIN` like so:

```
SELECT s.*, SUM(IFNULL(sd.fiyat, 0)) as konak
FROM fuar_sozlesme1 s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fuar_sozlesme1_detay sd ON sd.sozlesme_id = s.id
GROUP BY s.someFields
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example, you may help: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41481/1

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but I spent a couple of hours trying to solve the same issue.

My query has two joins, a filter and a SUM function.  I'm no SQL expert, but this helped me achieve the desired result of still showing a result even if the joined table had no rows to sum.

The key for me in order to show results even if the sum was totaling nothing, was the GROUP BY.  I'm still not 100% sure why.

The two types of joins were chosen based on this article - [MySQL Multiple Joins in one query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974328/mysql-multiple-joins-in-one-query)

```
SELECT registrations.reg_active, registrations.team_id, registrations.area_id, registrations.option_id, registrations.reg_fund_goal, registrations.reg_type, registrations.reg_fee_paid, registrations.reg_has_avatar, users.user_name, users.user_email, users.user_phone, users.user_zip, users.user_age, users.user_gender, users.user_active, SUM(IFNULL(donations.donation_amount,0)) as amt from registrations
    INNER JOIN `users` 
        ON registrations.user_id = users.user_id
        AND registrations.event_id = :event_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `donations` 
        ON registrations.reg_id = donations.reg_id
    GROUP BY donations.reg_id
    ORDER BY users.user_name ASC
```