# removing time from datetime in c# and retaining datetime format

Tags: c#

How can I remove time from datetime and store the output in datetime format? I do not want to show the time.

Say I have

```
string d = "2/27/2013 4:18:53 PM"
```

How can I store the output in a DateTime variable with only the date and not time.

I can use ToShortDateString() but then it return a string and not datetime.

My ultimate goal is to sort the date column chronologically which can only be done if all the entries are in datetime format and not string.

Comment: you have datetime column on database, you want to sort by date?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property of the `DateTime` struct will give you a date but it will always have a time component that represents midnight ("00:00:00"). If you're starting with a string, you might be able to work with something like this:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse("2/27/2013 4:18:53 PM").Date; // 2/27/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

Just make sure you perform your comparison on `DateTime` objects (i.e. omit all usages of `ToString()`).

Alternatively, you can format your date in the ["sortable" time format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Sortable):

```
string d = DateTime.Parse("2/27/2013 4:18:53 PM").ToString("s");
```

or

```
string d = yourDateTime.ToString("s");
```

For the above case `d` would be `2013-02-27T16:18:53`. When sorted alphabetically, the strings will be in chronological order.

Comment: Sorry. This outputs 2/27/2013 12:00:00 AM. I do not want the time part.

Comment: @bluepiranha: If you're comparing `DateTime` objects instead of strings, it shouldn't matter that it outputs the time part. If *every* time part is exactly the same, then it will have no affect on the sorting (again, when you are **not** comparing strings, but actual `DateTime`s).

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is exhaustive and well researched.

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.now();      (To get Any Date)

string datewithMonth= dt.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");

string onlyDate = DateTime.Parse(datewithMonth).ToShortDateString();
```

Here we get result as `1/1/2014`. So that we can perform select operation on sql like this:

```
searchQuery = "select * from YourTableName where ColumnName = '  " + onlyDate + " '   ";
```

Answer (score 1):

As easy as this:

```
d.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy");
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(d);
```

Comment: This answer is just plain wrong. In the question, `d` is a string, not a `DateTime`.

Comment: Ok, but am I mistaken? Is `d` not a string? Furthermore, even if `d` were a `DateTime`, `d.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy");` would not change it or set it in any way.

Answer (score 1):

What about removing the time in culture:-

```
        var submissionDateData = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        var submissionDate = DateTime.Parse(submissionDateData, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));
```

First line gives 02/11/2015

Second line gives 11/02/2015 12:00:00 AM

Do you have to do a string split on this or is there a way to get rid of the time?