# Calculate annual date with current date in mvc4

Tags: c#, jquery, mysql, asp.net-mvc-4

i need to calculate annual date with current date in mvc ..

Let us take today date, i want to display 2017/mar/24 in my textbox calculating with current date.. 
Is there any option to calculate date using csharp or jquery?

Comment: @Kartikeya Khosla `DateTime date = new DateTime(2016, 3, 24).Date; //OR DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date;
DateTime newDate = date.AddYears(1);` IT WILL DISPLAY TIME ALSO

Comment: @Karthikeya khosla  it is possible but i want to save this to database too in that case it is not possible !!

Answer (score 4):

C#

Use [**AddYears()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addyears(v=vs.110).aspx) :-

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2016, 3, 24); //OR DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
DateTime newDate = date.AddYears(1);
```

**Edit :-** If you need only **date** part.

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2016, 3, 24).Date; //OR DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date;
DateTime newDate = date.AddYears(1);
```

The `.Date` property will set the time part of DateTime object to `00:00:00`, if you want to completely remove time part then convert date to string as `newDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");`

You can read more about custom date format in this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

**NOTE :-** C# DateTime will always have time part(even if you use `.Date` it will set time to `00:00:00`), if you want to completely remove time then you have to convert datetime to string(as shown above).

Comment: is it possible to write code like **Datetime date=new DateTme(DateTime.Now)** ???? it shows an error

Comment: @Souparnika..`DateTime.Now` will itself return current datetime object I don't think passing `DateTime.Now` inside `DateTime` constructor make any sense...why you want to do this?

Comment: DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date

Comment: If you want just current datetime use `DateTime date = DateTime.Now` as mentioned my answer as well.

Comment: ok thanks .. if i need only current date **DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date DateTime newDate = date.AddYears(1);** is it possible?

Comment: @Souparnika...YES..you can extract date from datetime and add a year in it as you shown above it will set the time to `00:00:00`.

Comment: But i dont want to display time .. is there any option for this?

Comment: @Souparnika..plz refer there SO thread..[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27561530/how-to-remove-time-portion-of-date-in-c-sharp-in-datetime-object-only) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326709/removing-time-from-datetime-in-c-sharp-and-retaining-datetime-format)

Comment: `DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date;
            string dates= date.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy");
            DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse(dates);
            DateTime newDate = date.AddYears(1);
            ViewBag.Date = newDate;` i need to save this ViewBag.Date into database is it possile to save this in datetime field?? no i got en exception while running this

Comment: @Karthikeya khosla it is possible but i want to save this to database too in that case it is not possible !!

Comment: **string dates = newDate.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy");** in this case one more bug too it will display motnh ass 00??

Comment: @Souparnika..I think as per question.. the answer fully solve the problem if you have other problems/questions instead of asking in the comments, ask a new question.

Comment: string dates = newDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") Could not able to save this to database is it possible to convert this???

Comment: @Souparnika..I don't know much about mysql but `string dates = newDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` will provide you only date in string format and if your mysql column accept it then it should save without any problem as I have said i am not familiar with mysql.If you have another question regarding mysql post a question under mysql tag.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript:

```
    var fullDate = new Date();
    var twoDigitMonth = ((fullDate.getMonth().length+1) === 1)? (fullDate.getMonth()+1) : '0' + (fullDate.getMonth()+1);
    var next_year = parseInt(fullDate.getFullYear())+1;
    var annualdate = next_year + "/" + twoDigitMonth + "/" + fullDate.getDate();
```