# Sharing table data with each other

Tags: php, mysqli

Hello I am a pc and laptop repair man and wanted to build an offline database site where I can enter details about repairs, clients and invoices.
I have a very basic knowledge of sqli and php as I have only just started to try to learn it.

Currently I have 3 tables in my database which is not linked to each other. I use 3 forms to submit the data into them.

**CLIENTS**

```
Id – name – surname – phone – address
```

**REPAIRS**

```
Id – name – surname – phone – address – unit – date – price
```

**INVOICE**

```
Id - paidstatus – date paid - name – surname – phone – address- unit – date – price
```

Due to my lack of knowledge I am displaying the data onto 3 different pages

```
Clients.php
Repairs.php
Invoices.php
```

This is not the ideal solution for me but done this as my knowledge is very basic.
For example when I go to my form to add a new repair I wanted to pull the information from the clients table and use the details of: name – surname – phone – address
Then on invoice I like to call the data from the other tables.

I think what I am after is called Database normalization and I have got some links but am after someone’s expertise regarding a few questions...

This is the current way I am pulling data from my tables above I have used examples so the code might not reflect on the table’s names or rows.

```
  <?php
    //include database connection
    include 'db_connect.php';

    //query all records from the database
    $query = "select * from repair_jobs";

    //execute the query
    $result = $mysqli->query( $query );

    //get number of rows returned
    $num_results = $result->num_rows;

    //this will link us to our add.php to create new record
    if( $num_results > 0){ //it means there's already a database record

        //start table
        //creating our table heading
        echo " <table class='table_basic'>";
        echo "<thead><tr>";
            echo "<th>Job #</th>";
            echo "<th>Name Of Unit</th>";
            echo "<th>Client</th>";
            echo "<th>Estimated Value</th>";
        echo "</thead></tr><tbody><tr>";

        //loop to show each records
        while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
                //extract row
                //this will make $row['firstname'] to
                //just $firstname only
                extract($row);

                //creating new table row per record
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td width='40px'><a href='rdetails.php?id={$id}'># {$id}</a></td>";
                    echo "<td>{$type}</td>";
                    echo "<td>{$notes}</td>";
    echo '<td align="center"><span class="badge badge-success">£';
    include('repairest.php');
    echo '</span></td>';

                                    echo "</td>";
                echo "";
        }

        echo "</tr></table>";//end table

    }else{
        //if database table is empty
        echo "No records found.";
    }

    //disconnect from database
    $result->free();
    $mysqli->close();

    ?>
```

How different would it be to pull the information using normalization? Also can anyone post a link to an easy tutorial maybe with the tutorial source files downloadable?

Also how different would be the form be to input the data?

---

**UPATE**

---

regarding miah answer

how would the tables be created and joined via sql? i see the exampleon the page you linked under this question in the comments field but could you show me the ways to join this as

one to one and multiple.

am i right to think, that when i add a new repair i would use my form only to add 
  unit – date – price
but what if a client isn't created? or would the client have to be made first?

something like

CLIENT: Old(drop down) or New (button) (might need a snippet of code for this what is it called so i can do some research)

then i would enter the repairs data.

The invoice can be generated after as all the information needed would be available from the repair table and

Comment: Here is a good place to get started: [intro to normalization](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html).

Comment: Thank you for your comment and link, I have started to go through it. in my case what they refer to as the ISBN table would be my contact table. is there a way to get hold of the source files for this so i can see it in a working environment? i learn better that way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find one with source code, but [here is one with some diagrams](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/179103-relational-database-design-normalization/).

The key is that you don't want to repeat data across tables, so for example, you could modify your tables to look like this:

**CLIENTS**

```
Id – name – surname – phone – address
```

**REPAIRS**

```
Id – client_id – unit – date – price
```

**INVOICE**

```
Id - repair_id - paidstatus – date paid
```

1. client to repairs is a one-to-many relationship, i.e. 1 client can have many repairs, and a repair can have only 1 client.
2. clients to invoice is a one-to-many relationship through repairs, i.e. 1 client can have many invoices, and a invoice can have only 1 client.
3. repairs to invoice is one-to-one, and I think this could be an issue, because it might make sense to have multiple repairs tied to a single invoice, but it is a good place to start.

you could always start with the invoice, and have a foreign key in the repair to an invoice, instead of the client.  This is a bit of a swap in terms of business logic, but I think it would give you greater flexibility going forward:

**CLIENTS**

```
Id – name – surname – phone – address
```

**INVOICE**

```
Id - client_id - paidstatus – date paid
```

**REPAIRS**

```
Id – invoice_id – unit – date – price
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, let's assume that you decided to keep up with your original model, rather than the modified version I mentioned.  You would create each table just like you do now, and you would just make sure that `client_id` in **repairs** was the same data type as `id` in clients.

Then you can use JOIN ([Here is an SO answer that talks about SQL JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8974371/1572077)) to run a single query to pull out the data:

```
# all the data
SELECT * FROM invoices i JOIN repairs r ON i.repair_id = r.id JOIN clients c ON r.client_id = c.id

# all the data for a specific customer
SELECT * FROM invoices i JOIN repairs r ON i.repair_id = r.id WHERE r.client_id = <id goes here>

# Also, if JOINs seem intimidating, you can reference multiple tables
# and link them all together in a where clause
SELECT * FROM invoices i, repairs r, clients c WHERE i.repair_id = r.id AND r.client_id = c.id

# But you don't always need to get all of the data at once.  
# It makes a lot of sense to grab only what you need and create links to detail pages.
# So grab all of the unpaid invoices, and provide a link to a page that write that
# shows the client and repair details associated with that invoice
SELECT * FROM invoices i WHERE i.paidstatus='unpaid'
```

Now you still have to create the clients first, but then in the create repair form, you would have a select box that contained options with the id from the client table as the value.

```
//query all records from the database
$query = "select id, name, surname from clients";

//execute the query
$result = $mysqli->query( $query );

echo("<select name='client_id'>");
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
   echo("<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . " " . $row['surname'] . "</option>";
}
echo("</select>");
```

Yes, you could have new client fields in the repair form, it just adds complexity to the database insertion, so it is up to you.

The basic idea here is that you grab the id's from the table for that data that you want your other table to reference.  That way if client_A changes their phone number, you only have to change it one place.

Comment: I have read your answer and it is making sence. but i have updated the question.

Comment: thank you for such a indepth answer. i have managed to get the second part to work but needing some help on how to display the client data

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href = "Page.php?View=Invoices">View Invoices</a>
<a href = "Page.php?View=Repairs">View Repairs</a>
<a href = "Page.php?View=Clients">View Clients</a>



<?php

  if (isset($_GET['View'])){

    //query all records from the database
    $query = "select * from ".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['View']);

    //execute the query
    $result = $mysqli->query( $query );
  }
```

A method similar to this, would work wonders and allow you to keep the views to one page. Providing your database setups are more or less the same, in individual cases you should validate views per the results of `$_GET['View'];` If:

```
if ($_GET['View'] === "Test_1"){
  echo "Validate as Clients";
}elseif ($_GET['View'] === "Test_2"){
 echo "Validate as Repairs";
}elseif ($_GET['View'] === "Test_3"){
 echo "Validate as Invoices";
}
```

This is a demonstration, you should adapt this code/findings into your own environment

Comment: Thank you for your answer i see what you are saying and will be better for me to use this method then what i am using currently with the different pages