# MySQL inner join fails

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I got this simple join statement and I'm pretty sure the syntax is correct. I looked some tutorials and I don't find any difference between my code and the exemples.
Here's the statement:

```
SELECT n.id nId, n.news_date, n.news_type,
       p.id pId, p.title pTitle, p.file_path pPath,
       s.id sId, s.title sTitle, s.content sContent,
       v.id vId, v.title vTitle, v.url vUrl
FROM photo_news p, standard_news s, video_news v
INNER JOIN news n
ON p.news_id = n.id OR s.news_id = n.id OR v.news_id = n.id
ORDER BY n.news_date DESC
```

I get the following error:

> Unknown column 's.news_id' in 'on clause'

I really don't know why this error is launched because the column 'news_id' exists in every table it has to exist.
And if I change the order in the ON clause (i.e. I start with p.news_id = n.news_id) I get the same error (unknwonw column p.news_id). So I think there's a problem with the aliases but I really don't have a clue.
Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Don't mix legacy join syntax with the explicit join syntax.

Comment: can you use OR in an ON statement?

Comment: @juergend I agree with you on mixing (in fact, avoid comma join altogether) - but is it 'legacy'?

Comment: @Strawberry: [Yes](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Outer_join)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are looking for something like this to return data for the record in photo news with data in at least one of the other table.

In that case you need to use a LEFT JOINs and not OR in the JOIN conditions.

```
         SELECT n.id nId, n.news_date, n.news_type,
                p.id pId, p.title pTitle, p.file_path pPath,
                s.id sId, s.title sTitle, s.content sContent,
                v.id vId, v.title vTitle, v.url vUrl
           FROM news n
LEFT OUTER JOIN photo_news p
             ON n.id = p.news_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN standard_news s
             ON n.id = s.news_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN video_news v
             ON n.id = v.news_id 
WHERE p.news_id IS NOT NULL
   OR s.news_id IS NOT NULL
   OR v.news_id IS NOT NULL

   ORDER BY n.news_date DESC
```

Comment: All of the answers look good, thank you guys. However I'm not very good at SQL so I don't knwow which one I should choose. Let me explain: _news_ could be considered as the "super table" and _photo_news_, _standard_news_, _video_news_ the "inherited tables". In fact in the application these are my entities. I'd like to retrieve all the news regardless of their type, which statement should I choose ?

Comment: Finally I tried all the solutions and this one is exactly what I want, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You made mistake in JOINing tables.
[for reference you can see how multiple tables are JOINed together.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8974371/435559)

```
SELECT n.id nId, n.news_date, n.news_type,
       p.id pId, p.title pTitle, p.file_path pPath,
       s.id sId, s.title sTitle, s.content sContent,
       v.id vId, v.title vTitle, v.url vUrl
FROM photo_news p INNER JOIN standard_news s       
p.news_id = s.news_id
INNER JOIN video_news v
on s.news_id = v.news_id
INNER JOIN news n
on v.news_id = n.id
ORDER BY n.news_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing only-style and new-style joins.  Just use the explicit `join` syntax.  Your `from` should probably be:

```
FROM news n join
     photo_news p
     on p.news_id = n.id join
     standard_news s
     on s.news_id = n.id join
     video_news v
     on v.news_id = n.id
```

Using `or` between `join` conditions is not typically used.

THe error is appearing because of the precedence rules that MySQL uses.  As the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) explains:

> INNER JOIN and , (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of
>   a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product between the
>   specified tables (that is, each and every row in the first table is
>   joined to each and every row in the second table).
>
> However, the precedence of the comma operator is less than of INNER
>   JOIN, CROSS JOIN, LEFT JOIN, and so on. If you mix comma joins with
>   the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the
>   form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur. Information
>   about dealing with this problem is given later in this section.

All that said, I'm not sure that this is really the query that you want.  You are going to get a cartesian product of the different values from the different tables.  You should probably ask another question with sample data and desired results, so someone can help you with the right query.

Answer (score 0):

You are using deprecated join syntax mixed with supported syntax.
do yourself a favor and write those joins properly

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

```
SELECT n.id nId, n.news_date, n.news_type,
       p.id pId, p.title pTitle, p.file_path pPath,
       s.id sId, s.title sTitle, s.content sContent,
       v.id vId, v.title vTitle, v.url vUrl
FROM photo_news p
left/inner/right/"" join standard_news s on CONDITION
left/inner/right/""  join video_news v on CONDITION
INNER JOIN news n
ON p.news_id = n.id OR s.news_id = n.id OR v.news_id = n.id
ORDER BY n.news_date DESC
```

However, i am pretty sure you want to use union or something

```
SELECT ... 

FROM 
select * from (photo_news p
union all standard_news s 
union all video_news v ) all_news
INNER JOIN news n on CONDITION
```