# PHP mysql display multiple tables in single table

Tags: php, html, mysql, join

Is there away to join 3 tables by two attribute names and still display that entire row?

We have 3 tables, sports(event type, team 1, team 2, place, time, date, price)
                  concert(artist, time, date, place, opening act and price) and restaurants(place, name, special and date)

I want to join them with sports.date, concert.date, sports.place, concert.place and  restaurant.place

But i want it to show the rest of the attributes in the rest of the rows for each table.

Comment: could you post some example data and the expected result?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974328/mysql-multiple-joins-in-one-query) will probably help you out, you basically just need 2 joins in your SQL query.

Comment: this is just the sports notnormalmotorsports.com/NiteKrawler will give you the sports table tell i can get it to display the 3 tables.

Comment: wont that only display those columns?

Comment: You can select any column by using the `table.column` syntax in your SQL query. Initially, you might just want to use `SELECT * ...` to see everything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Multiple Joins in one query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974328/mysql-multiple-joins-in-one-query)