# Connect to multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

How can I connect to 4 tables in a single query using forign key IDs?

I know how to connect to two tables.

```
$sql = "SELECT tb1.id, tb2.name FROM tblA tbl1 LEFT JOIN tblB tbl2 ON tb1.id = tbl2.studentID ORDER BY tbl1.id DESC LIMIT 20";
$statement = $con_db->prepare($sql);
```

Comment: share your table structure in question

Comment: You can use multiple joins

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Multiple Joins in one query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974328/mysql-multiple-joins-in-one-query)

Comment: You may want to use mulitple joins, however it might be more efficient to use subqueries, especially if you are only retrieving a single field from each of the additional tables.  What do you want in your output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this :

```
select t1.ID, t2.studentID, t3.aID, t4.bID 
from  table1 as t1

left join tbl2 as t2 on t2.studentID = t1.id
left join tbl3 as t3 on t3.aID = t1.id
left join tbl4 as t4 on t4.bID = t1.id
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me give it a try.