# How do I inner join and group by multiple times?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing a query that should return a report of the total number of public health workers working in the facility, the total number of doses people have received in the facility, and the total number of doses scheduled by people to be vaccinated in the facility in the future. I divided the task by three SQL codes:

-- 1 total number of public health workers working in the facility

```
SELECT `name`,  address, phone, type, phone, capacity, COUNT(person_id) AS totalWorkers
FROM healthcare_worker
INNER JOIN facility ON facility.`name`= healthcare_worker.facility_name
GROUP BY healthcare_worker.facility_name
```

-- 2 the total number of doses people have received in the facility

```
SELECT `name`,  address, phone, type, phone, capacity, SUM(dose) AS totalDose
FROM vaccination
INNER JOIN facility ON facility.`name`= vaccination.location
GROUP BY vaccination.location
```

-- 3  the total number of doses scheduled by people to be vaccinated in the facility in the future

```
SELECT `name`,  address, phone, type, phone, capacity, COUNT(booking_id) AS totalBookings 
FROM booking
INNER JOIN facility ON facility.`name`= booking.facility_name
GROUP BY booking.facility_name
```

Can I put them together into one query?

Comment: Combine how? Show us 3 results, and how you want them to be combined. (All as formatted text, no images.)

Comment: You'll get a better answer if you just provide the sample data for each table and your desired results.

Comment: you can check answers to similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974328/mysql-multiple-joins-in-one-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use correlated sub-queries

```
SELECT `name`, address, phone, `type`, capacity
, ( SELECT COUNT(person_id)
    FROM healthcare_worker
    WHERE fac.`name`= healthcare_worker.facility_name
  ) AS totalWorkers
, ( SELECT SUM(dose)
    FROM vaccination
    WHERE fac.`name`= vaccination.location
  ) AS totalDose
, ( SELECT COUNT(booking_id)
    FROM booking
    WHERE fac.`name`= booking.facility_name
  ) AS totalBookings
FROM facility AS fac
```

| name | address | phone | type | capacity | totalWorkers | totalDose | totalBookings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| finalcare | venice | 00 00 04 | morgue | 4 | 3 | 15 | 3 |
| wevac | xxx | 79 72 04 | private | 69 | 3 | 6 | 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a32c5f3a422675c9424f03e7cf9f84be)*